# Elementary existence proof in first order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Please forgive my dullness but I just don't know how to - formally - show that

$$\lbrace \forall x\ \phi(x), \exists x\ x = x \rbrace \vdash \exists x\ \phi(x)$$

for an arbitrary formula $\phi(x)$.

It seems easy when there are individual constants:

$$\forall x\ \phi(x)\vdash \phi(a) $$

$$\phi(a) \vdash \exists x\ \phi(x)$$

But when the language doesn't contain individual constants, and $\exists x\ x = x$ is all  that I know?

Comment: Universal instantiation and Existential generalisation may be applied to any _term_. Free variables are also terms.

Comment: Would you please be so kind and explain this in more detail? I don't see no free variables in my expressions.

Comment: Well we are always supplied with an infinitude of variables. E.g. if $y$ does not occur in $\phi$ then $\forall x \phi(x) \vdash \phi(y)$ is a valid instance of universal instantiation.

Comment: @Hans: It is probably worth clarifying if your setting allows empty domains. e.g. from your exposition it sounds like $\exists x: x=x$ is **not** a tautology. It should be stated explicitly, to avoid confusing people who are used to empty domains being excluded.

Comment: How could I - formally - clarify that my setting allows (or not) empty domains? And I did not intend $\exists x : x = x$ to be a tautology - just a contingent fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y$ be a variable not occuring at all in $\phi(x)$. Then we have $$\forall x\;\phi(x)\vdash\phi(y)$$ per *Universal Instantiation* and then $$\phi(y)\vdash\exists x\;\phi(x)$$ (because $x$ does not occur in $\phi(y)$) per *Existential Generalization*.

How come we don't even need $\exists x\;x=x$? Well, the rules of inference already incorporate that our universe of discourse is nonempty (variables are not of type "pink unicorn").

Comment: I just noted (after reading @Lord_Farin's comment abbove) that one indeed needs a "new" variable $y$ to really obey the restrictions imposed on the rules of inference used.

Comment: So I just have been mistaken and $\forall x\ \phi(x)$ really *implies* $\exists x\ \phi(x)$? I would be happy, but I still feel insecure. But most probably I did not have digested the concepts of *universal instantiation* and *existential generalization* enough.

Comment: In some proof systems, you don't even need to use a new variable $y$.  You could use $x$ instead of $y$, since $x$ doesn't appear _free_ in $\forall x\,\phi(x)$.

Comment: @HansStricker, you might not have a confusion about _universal instantiation_ and _existential generalization_, but perhaps about [_existential import_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_import#Existential_import), which is typically assumed in first-order logic, and says that the domain of discourse is non-empty.  Then, $\forall x\,\phi(x) \vdash \exists x\,\phi(x)$ might be a little more intuitive:  Since _everything_ has property $\phi$ and, by existential import, there _is_ something, then _something_ has property $\phi$.

Comment: Actually it is the premise $\exists x~x=x$ that says *"there is something"* (specifically, something that equals itself, but it is the *existence* that is useful here). We have that when *everything is phi*, and there *is something*, then *something is phi*.  $$\forall x~\phi(x), \exists x~\psi(x)\vdash \exists x~\phi(x)$$